# How to update with more condition using join table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have two table with data sample, i want to update data in TableA with condition .
TableA sample

```
ID  Product     Price
001 Apple       Null
002 Orange      Null
```

TableB Sample

```
ID  Product     Type    Price
001 Apple       H       10
001 Apple       M       7
002 Orange      M       8
003 Banana      H       20
003 Banana      M       14
```

And i try with as follow

```
Update A
Set A.Price = isnull( (select B.Price where B.Type = 'H') , isnull(select B.Price where B.Type = 'M', 0))
from TableA A inner join TableB B on A.ID = B.ID
```

I want result as

```
ID  Product     Price
001 Apple       10
002 Orange      8
```

But it's not working

Comment: What is your expected result here?

Comment: Update data in TableA, thank you.

Comment: That's what you want to do, not your expected results.

Comment: sorry , i add more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @TableA AS TABLE(ID INT, Product VARCHAR(20),Price INT)
INSERT INTO @TableA
SELECT 001,'Apple',       Null UNION ALL
SELECT 002,'Orange',      Null

DECLARE @TableB AS TABLE (ID INT,Product VARCHAR(20),[Type] VARCHAR(2),Price INT)
INSERT INTO @TableB
SELECT 001,'Apple'  ,'H',10 UNION ALL
SELECT 001,'Apple'  ,'M',7  UNION ALL
SELECT 002,'Orange' ,'M',8  UNION ALL
SELECT 003,'Banana' ,'H',20 UNION ALL
SELECT 003,'Banana' ,'M',14



UPDATE A
SET A.Price = ISNULL(CASE B.[Type] WHEN 'H' THEN B.Price
                                    WHEN 'M' THEN B.Price END,0)
FROM @TableA A
INNER JOIN @TableB B ON A.ID=B.ID

SELECT * FROM @TableA
```

Result

```
ID  Product Price
----------------
1   Apple   10
2   Orange  8
```

Comment: This will most likely yield wrong answer in cases when first row is the M row. example `SELECT 001,'Apple'  ,'M',7 UNION ALL
SELECT 001,'Apple'  ,'H',10  UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

you should use a query like below

```
update A
set A.price=B.price
from TableA A left join
(
select
   id,Price= 
    coalesce( max( case when Type='H' then Price end), max(case when type='M' then Price end), 0 )
from TableB B
group by ID
)B on A.Id=B.Id
```